# Need to show 4 list only - slideDown jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown

Here i have 8 list but i want show only 4 lists with more button after clicking the more button rest of the list will show. please help me out.

Here jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion").hide();
  $('#acc').click(function() {
    if ($("#accordion").is(":hidden")) {
    $("#accordion").slideDown("fast");
    } 
    else {  $("#accordion").hide(); }       
  });
})  ;
```

and html

```
<div>
<h1 style="font-size:12px;"  id="acc">Product</h1>
<div id="accordion">
<ul>
<li>Link1</li>
<li>Link2</li>
<li>Link3</li>
<li>Link4</li>
<li>Link5</li>
<li>Link6</li>
<li>Link7</li>
<li>Link8</li>
</ul>
<span id="more"><a href="#">More</a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: One issue that jumps out. Your "more" button is inside the hidden accordion.

Comment: more button is also hide when refreshing the page. clicking the product 4 list will display with more button.

Comment: @J. Steen It's not an issue. This button should be visible only if accordion is visible with 4 elements at first.

Comment: @avall, It -won't- be an issue, but it is right now, with the current code... yes? =)

Comment: @J. Steen I'd say once more it isn't any issue. This button is placed in correct place.

Comment: @avall, Ah! I totally missed that they first -show- the accordion with the "acc" header. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion").hide().find("li:gt(3)").hide();

  $('#acc').click(function() {
    if ($("#accordion").is(":hidden")) {
    $("#accordion").slideDown("fast");
    } 
    else {  $("#accordion").hide(); }       
  });

  $("#more").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    $("#accordion li").show();
  });
});
```